# Merging behavioral methods to a PHP class

Tags: php, oop, abstract

Let's say i have the following behavior and standard class:

```
abstract class MyBehavior {
     function testFunction(){
         return 'test';
     }
}

class TestClass {
     var $use = array('MyBehavior');

     function __construct(){
         // do something to give me access to function testFunction through
         // $this->testFunction();
     }
}

$test = new TestClass();
```

As i commented, i would like the MyBehavior method to be available inside TestClass ($test->testFunction();) without "extending" the class...

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** Thanks for all the responses, I have my answer, or at least i need to know what my options are, so thanks! I can only give one right answer, so I'm going with the first response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php

trait MyBehavior {

    public function testFunction() 
    {
        return 'test';
    }

}

class TestClass {

    use MyBehavior;

    function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->testFunction();
    }

}

$test = new TestClass();
```

You could use a [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) to add your desired behavior to a class. Traits exist since PHP >= 5.4.0 and are a neat way to extend classes without actually making use of inheritance. **But be careful:**

If misused, traits will be in your way more than they help you. Anthony Ferrera wrote a really good blogpost about the downsides of traits. So **[you should definitely give it a read](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/07/are-traits-new-eval.html)**.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Traits are only available for PHP versions 5.4 and newer.

Comment: I've added some additional information about traits.

Comment: That's great news, and thanks! The question remains, how would that be done before 5.4... i think my live server is Ubu 12.04 anmd php 5.3.1 so is there a way to do that as well???

Comment: See @deceze 's answer, which should be applicable before PHP 5.4. You need to replace the short array literals (`[]`) with the old `array()` though. If his answer did the trick for you please mark his one as accepted answer. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24430406/1420347)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using >= PHP 5.4 you can use traits but this example won't do anything as constructors can't return values:

```
trait MyBehavior 
{
     public function testFunction()
     {
         return 'test';
     }
}

class TestClass 
{
    use MyBehavior;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->testFunction();
    }
}

$test = new TestClass();
```

Answer (score 2):

Traits really are the way to go. You can hack something together without traits though. You have to make `MyBehavior` not-abstract for this to work:

```
class TestClass {

    protected $use = ['MyBehavior'];
    protected $_behaviors = [];

    public function __construct() {
        foreach ($this->use as $behavior) {
            $this->_behaviors[] = new $behavior;
        }
    }

    public function __call($name, $args) {
        foreach ($this->_behaviors as $behavior) {
            if (method_exists($behavior, $name)) {
                return call_user_func_array([$behavior, $name], $args);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Not very pretty though.

Comment: I think that is pretty tightly coupled (but so is using traits). Maybe you could drop the `$use` property and pass an array of "behavior" instances to the constructor, which would decouple the class a bit and would make it even a better argument against traits? Just a thought

Comment: Oh, certainly, I'd never use this in practice. I've been plagued with CakePHP for a while and this exactly one of the things that makes it so bad.

Comment: That's what my thinking was, i know the use like that from CakePHP and i really don't like the way that gets loaded, but thanks very much for the reponse and clarification!

Answer (score 0):

A bit tricky but you could do something like this too:

```
abstract class MyBehavior 
{
     function testFunction()
     {
         return 'test';
     }
}

class TestClass {
     var $cls = array('MyBehavior');

     function __construct(){
         echo call_user_func(array($this->cls[0], 'testFunction'));
     }
}

$test = new TestClass();
```

[Example online](http://ideone.com/PM6fN9)

Comment: Non-static method should not be called statically, if it works, it does not mean it should be done that way. Your second example is also a static call.

Comment: @baldrs alright, could you please tell me a reference in the docs, that this should never been used this way? I see that this is not recommended but I don't see this is prohibited. And in this particular case, to not rewrite a bunch of code, this can be useful

Comment: This would work through the __call method i guess, but it's all a bit messy, thanks though!